# I am not able to run an api using curl method on live server

Tags: php, curl, error-handling, magento-1.9

On localhost sms working

[image: localhost_sms working]I using curl to hit an api, I tried this method on localhost and its working fine as i want , but when i copied same method to live website it stop working on live website.

$msg ="Some Custom msg here";

`$msgencoded = urlencode($msg);`   // message is enocded
`$numEncode = urlencode($telePhone);`  // Telephone is enocded

NOTE :i am getting this variable correctly.  `$telephone`

**API as per API document**

```
   $url = "http://msg_server_website.com:8080/SMSAPI.jsp?
   username=user_name&
   password=user_pwd&
   sendername=sender_name&
   mobileno=".$numEncode."&message=".$msgencoded."";

My curl function which is working on localhost.

     $data = $msg;
                $crl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                $response = curl_exec($crl);    




     if ($response) {
    // if curl_exec() returned false and thus failed
    echo 'everything was successful';
}
else {
    echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($crl);
}
   curl_close($crl);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
error has occurred: Failed to connect to websitename.com port 8080: Connection refused
```

I am trying many times i got this error. what to do in this case.

**UPDATE 2**

8080 port is blocked on client  server.  What to do, How to unblock the port.

**UPDATE 3**
My problem is solved now , as in my case its PORT issue of 8080 which is not free on client host,now ever thing works as expected.

Thank you everyone for support.

Comment: That code shouldn't work on your localhost either, since you're actually _closing_ curl before your if-statement (which also deletes the curl handler `$crl`). You've already got a response, use that in your if-statement instead of trying to make the same call again..

Comment: @ i added this error check part on live website only , after updating the code i got above error. Can you see once

Comment: You're still making the call twice. Try checking `if ($response)` instead, since you've already have the result there. The site might have protection against two identical calls from the same client directly after each other. Also, you should really `urlencode()` both the phone number and message.

Comment: `error has occurred: Failed to connect to websitename.com port 8080: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this post, I am posting this as answer.

My problem is solved now , as in my case its PORT issue of 8080 which is not free on client host,now ever thing works as expected.

I checked with the server provider (Godady in this case).As client is using shared hosting so port can not freed for individual person.

so i talked to sms provider and they suggested some changes related to port and my API now run successfully.